# NoClassDefFoundError when running mahout spark-itemsimilarity

Tags: apache-spark, mahout

I am new to mahout and want to run the command "mahout spark-itemsimilarity" according to this page [intro-coocurrence-spark](http://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html). However I get the following error, I googled a lot but still get nothing related to this?

```
./bin/mahout spark-itemsimilarity
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I am using Ubuntu and set up JAVA_HOME, MAHOUT_HOME, SPARK_HOME. what else I should do?

Comment: forgot to mention the versions I used, mahout 0.12.2, Hadoop 2.7.3

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: This looks like a Spark setup problem because one of the first things Spark looks for is SparkConf. Are you able to run any of the Spark demo apps or the Spark Scala shell?

Comment: spark version is 2.1.0. I haven't run any spark demo yet, I will do it. I saw some spark jar files included in the mahout folder, does that still need spark anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error after running the command "mahout spark-itemsimilarity".

I managed to get rid of this error by reverting to spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.4 in the directory to which SPARK_HOME points.

The idea to try this approach came as a result of reading 'Building From Source' section of README.md in a Mahout's directory, which I didn't read before because I use pre-built Mahout binaries.